# JS more input fields into one CF7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

Hi guys can somebody help me with my code in CF7. I need more input fields group into one. For example i have Street, City, State, zip. Please see the code below:

**CF7 code**

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h5>Address</h5>
                    <label>Address (Street)</label>                     
                    [text* current-address class:form-control id:cstreet]
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label>City</label>
                    [text* current-city class:form-control id:ccity]
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>State</label>
                    [select* current-country class:form-control  id:cstate include_blank "AL" "AK" "AZ" "AR" "CA" "CO" "CT" "DE" "FL" "GA" "HI" "ID" "IL" "IN" "IA" "KS" "KY" "LA" "ME" "MD" "MA" "MI" "MN" "MS" "MO" "MT" "NE" "NV" "NH" "NJ" "NM" "NY" "NC" "ND" "OH" "OK" "OR" "PA" "RI" "SC" "SD" "TN" "TX" "UT" "VT" "VA" "WA" "WV" "WI" "WY" "DC" "AE" "AA" "AP"]
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Zip</label>
                    [text* current-zip class:form-control id:czip]
                </div>
```

**CF7 display result**

*Street address

City, State, ZIP*

i want showing input information in dynamictext

`[dynamictext address-full]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will instantly read values typed into your fields and will update the full address dynamic field.

You also need to add id to your dynamictext `[dynamictext address-full id:addressfull]`

```
<script>
var cstreet = document.getElementById("cstreet");
var ccity = document.getElementById("ccity");
var cstate = document.getElementById("cstate");
var czip = document.getElementById("czip");
var addressfull = document.getElementById("addressfull");

if (cstreet) cstreet.addEventListener("input", updateFullAddress);
if (ccity) ccity.addEventListener("input", updateFullAddress);
if (cstate) cstate.addEventListener("input", updateFullAddress);
if (czip) czip.addEventListener("input", updateFullAddress);

function updateFullAddress (e) {
  if (addressfull) addressfull.value = `${cstreet.value} ${ccity.value} ${cstate.value} ${czip.value}`;  
}
</script>
```

Comment: did i need add the javascript to the footer of the theme?

Comment: yes, you can do this easily with Code Snippets plugin (there is an example for JS among the sample snippets). I edited my answer to check if the elements exist on the page. Please use the edited version.

Comment: thanks, i am using "Insert Headers and Footers" plugin for wordpress